# How do I abstract over defining a generic type within a generic type?

Tags: java, generics, abstraction

Say I have a HashMap of HashMaps defined like this:

```
hashMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>();
```

How would I abstract over this to make the definition more clear?

Comment: can you explain what is not clear about this?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: what do you want to make more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I interpret your question correctly, you have a collection which maps objects together and want to know if there is a way to do it that reads better.

It's best if we define a purpose for each of the elements, so as an example:

```
Map<String,        // ZIP code   (e.g. 6009)
    Map<String,    // Name       (e.g. John Smith)
        Integer>>  // Age        (e.g. 42)
```

In this case, you can create the following class:

```
class Person {
  private String name;
  private Integer age;

  // Constructor and getters etc.
}
```

This simplifies your collection to:

```
Map<String,         // ZIP/Postal code
    List<Person>>   // List of people in this postal code.
```

You can then simplify it further if you want, but this gives you an idea of what steps to take. The most important thing is to use names that make sense.

Comment: Good Idea, but would not `Map<ZIP,Map<Name,Age>>` be even better?

Comment: @emory That is definitely easy to understand, but introduces types where names are all that is needed. The use of a descriptive object `Person` to model the mapping between entities is the main point I was trying to show. Maps of Maps are (arguably) more difficult conceptually.

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want to have to repeat the definition again you can make it a class,  the definition is not unclear, just wordy..

```
class HashBrowns : HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make an abstract factory class. Usually those are good for creating abstract wrappers for concrete types in a generic fashion. Factories are often implemented as singletons, too.

Answer (score 0):

Without understanding more about your specific situation, the best that can be recommended are some methods to abstract out the storage method.

For example:

```
public Integer getNumber(String name, String attribute)
{
    HashMap<String,Integer> subMap = hashMap.get(name);
    if (subMap != null)
    {
        return subMap.get(attribute);
    } else
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public void setNumber(String name, String attribute, Integer number)
{
    HashMap<String,Integer> subMap = hashMap.get(name);
    if (subMap == null)
    {
        subMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        hashMap.put(name,subMap);
    }

    subMap.put(attribute,number);
}
```